# What's wrong with this jQuery example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following jQuery example should put some text into the div, but it doesn't. I tried Firefox, Google Chrome and Internet Explorer.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">

$(window).load(function() {

  $('adiv').html('<p>hello world</p>');
  alert('done');

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="adiv">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Sorry, this might be stupid, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Try type='text/javascript' instead of language. It's a deprecated attribute.

Comment: Thank you all. Sorry could only accept 1 answer. e-turhan was fastest.

Comment: Tim you are right. But I did this beause the question was answered very quickly after 2 minutes or so. But SO allows me to accept the answer after 10 minutes. I forgot to remove it later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

change `$('adiv').html('<p>hello world</p>');`to

```
$('#adiv').html('<p>hello world</p>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually selecting anything in your select function

Directly after your `$(` opening, you need to use a CSS3 valid selector. Just a string won't select anything unless it's a HTML element (`table`, `div`, `h2`)

You need to preface it with a `.` or a `#` to signal either a class or ID name.

Answer (score 0):

`$('adiv')` should be `$('#adiv')`.

Unlike Prototype, in jQuery you specify a CSS selector, not just a string that is implicitly inferred to be an ID. I find myself forgetting this from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

As e-turhan already mentioned you need `#` in front of `adiv` in your `$()` otherwise this is not a id selector. Also it's always better to call these `.load()` events inside the `.ready()` jQuery event whose famous shortcut is `$(function() { //execute when DOM is ready  });` . In your case:

```
$(function(){

$(window).load(
 function(){
   $('#adiv').html('<p>hello world</p>');   
 }

);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html> <head> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" language="javascript"></script> <script language="javascript">  $(window).load(function() {    $('#adiv').html('<p>hello world</p>');   alert('done');  }); </script> </head>  <body> <div id="adiv"> </div> </body>  </html>
```

**Paste this code instead ur query**

It Will Work

Answer (score -1):

Try $(document).ready(function()... instead of $(window).load(function()...